# Exclude Django Installed Apps while execute custom django command

Tags: python, django, django-commands

I have "xxx" in installed apps (settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
Inside this applications, I check on existing schema in Postgresql
If schema not exists I **throw the exception**.
I request a user to execute Django custom command (for create schema)

```sh
python manage.py create_schema ....
```

But this command can't execute because of `django.setup()` Django runs xxx app, which run exception about absent schema

I wanna temporarily exclude xxx app from Django while execute my custom command,  or maybe You have any suggestion

Comment: remove the app_name from `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`,this will exclude the app

Comment: but after finished this command I need this app

Comment: Put it back then... you just want to run a command, temporarily remove the app

Comment: I can't do it by myself, only by scripting, how can I do it?

Comment: You give me an idea to use different settings, but it, not excellent decision (

Comment: I am telling you to use other settings, I meant: remove the app that prevents you from running your scripts, and when it's done, put it back